# How do I add a user with explicit permissions to a repository in ADO?

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm tying to add a user to a repository in an existing team in Azure DevOps, but **only** with 'read only' access. The user in question has the ability to contribute to other repositories in other teams, and so I cannot simply add them to the 'Readers' ADO security team.

Whenever I try to go to the Repo security settings and "add" a user, the user appears and I can edit their permissions. However, if I navigate *anywhere* else within ADO or refresh the page, the user disappears - their permissions are not saved. I've tried disabling inheritance on the repository in question and adding the user again, but the same problem occurs. What's particularly strange is that I exist in the repo in question as both an explicit user, and a member of the project team.

To take this a step further, I tried adding the user in question to the project team and then trying to explicitly set permissions in the same way (adding them as an explicit user on the repo) but the same behaviour occurred.

Am I missing some team- or organisation-wide setting that prohibits the addition of individual users? Should I even be able to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to "Save changes" when you're done with the permissions.

[image]

Comment: I think... if the user being added is already a part of the groups that are added to the repo, and the permissions for the user aren't different than that of the group, then the user is removed because their "explicit" permissions are no different than their inherited permissions. So, if you missed the save button, this would remove the user and just use the group/team they are a part of.

Comment: Thanks Josh; your comment helped me a little more than your actual answer did - the 'correct' process seems to be to add the user AND immediately set their permissions. If you simply add the user but do not override any permissions, the save changes option is not available (implying there are no changes to be saved...) and the user is not persisted in the repo. Setting the permissions immediately and saving changes resolved the issue.

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that behavior while trying to repro. It seems like an issue with this section of the permissions, and might warrant a ticket created. Glad you got it sorted.